# Get all matching entries for a certain value in excel

Tags: excel

This is something I need for my computer science research thesis.
I have a big excel data file, with several columns, and two columns of interest are structured like this:

`Column A     Column B
--------     ---------
PersonType1   GroupType1
PersonType2   GroupType3
PersonType1   GroupType13
PersonType5   GroupType1
PersonType5   GroupType3`

What I would like to receive for each PersonType a list of its' GroupTypes. For example, I would like to have a result of: [PersonType1 = {GroupType1, GroupType13}], [PersonType2 = {GroupType3}], [PersonType5 = {GroupType1, GroupType3]]. (not necessarily syntactically-structured like this, just an example)

Is there a convenient set of actions I can do in excel to almost automate such info derivation?

If I were to do it manually, I would begin filtering for person type one at a time, and then copying its' B column. filter for the second person type, copy its' B column, but that is too much work.

I must mention that this comes after some filtering on the columns via excel's filter features.

Comment: Have you tried a Pivot Table ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an array formula (meaning, enter with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd>).

If your data is laid out like this:

[image]

Where Orange is the large table with all the data, and the Green row is the *unique* "PersonType#", you can put a formula below that to return just the values that match the type.

Then, use 
`=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$6,SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$6=F$2,ROW($A$2:$A$6)-ROW($A$2)+1),ROWS($A$2:$A2))),"")` 
and enter with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd>

[image]

and drag over and down a lot. (If your main data has 6 rows, drag the formula down at least 6 rows). When it doesn't find any more matches, it'll return `""`.